# Can't pass field populated by ajax to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hi I have a field that uses ajax to bring up product/item information

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="sku" />
<input type="button" name="Button" class="button" 
id="submit_btn" value="Search" onClick="showResult(sku.value)" />
```

js function:

```
function showResult(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getitem.php?sku="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

This works well and outputs the required data properly. However when I try to submit the form and capture the sku number entered and echo it I get "resource ID #5" which I've never seen before.

Here is the php:

```
$sku = $_POST['sku'];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$itemPrice = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM user WHERE sku = '.$sku.'");
<html>
<body>
<p><?php echo $itemPrice ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Essentially what i'm trying to do is take the sku number typed into the field "sku" and post it to a variable and echo it back after the form is submitted.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showResult(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?sku="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">
    <h1><a>Checkout</a></h1>
<form id="customForm" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="payment.php">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Checkout</h2>
            <p>Please fill in all fields to ensure your purchase is processed as quickly as possible. If you have any questions or concerns please contact us at support</p>
        </div>      
        <input type="text" size="30" id="sku" />
<input type="button" name="Button" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Search" onClick="showResult(sku.value)" />
<br />
<div id="description"></div>
            <ul >
                    <li id="li_11" >
        <label class="description" for="element_11">Voucher/Coupon Number </label>
        <div>
            <input id="voucher_number" name="voucher_number" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_voucher_number"><small>Please enter the voucher/coupon number received at the time of purchase</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <div><label class="description" for="bill_name">Name </label>
        <span>
            <input id="bill_first" name= "bill_first" class="element text" maxlength="15" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="bill_middle" name= "bill_middle" class="element text" maxlength="15" size="5" value=""/>
            <label>Middle</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="bill_last" name= "bill_last" class="element text" maxlength="15" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>Last</label>
        </span>
        <div id="nameInfo"></div></div>
        <p class="guidelines" id="guide_19"><small>Please enter your name as it appears on your credit card</small></p>
        </li>       <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Phone </label>
        <span>
            <input id="bill_area" name="bill_area" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
            <label for="bill_area">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="bill_fnum" name="bill_fnum" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text"> -
            <label for="bill_fnum">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="bill_lnum" name="bill_lnum" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
            <label for="bill_lnum">####</label>
        </span>

        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="email">Email</label>
        <div>
            <input id="email" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="35"/>
          <div class="error" id="emailInfo"></div>
          <p class="guidelines" id="guide_14"><small>Please enter your email address. This email will be used for all future communications between Overstock-King.com and yourself</small></p>
            </div>
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Billing Address </label>

        <div>
            <input id="bill_street" name="bill_street" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="bill_street">Street Address</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="bill_street_2" name="bill_street_2" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="bill_street_2">Address Line 2</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="bill_city" name="bill_city" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <label for="bill_city">City</label>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <select class="element select medium" input id="bill_province" name="bill_province">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="bc">British Columbia</option>
            <option value="alb">Alberta</option>
            <option value="sas">Saskatchewan</option>
            <option value="man">Manitoba</option>
            <option value="ont">Ontario</option>
            <option value="que">Quebec</option>
            <option value="nfl">Newfoundland & Labrador</option>
            <option value="nov">Nova Scotia</option>
            <option value="nwb">New Brunswick</option>
            <option value="pei">Prince Edward Island</option>
            <option value="ykn">Yukon</option>
            <option value="nwt">Northwest Territories</option>
            <option value="nun">Nunavut</option>
            </select>
            <label for="bill_province">Province</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="bill_postal" name="bill_postal" class="element text medium" maxlength="6" value="" type="text">
            <label for="bill_postal">Postal Code</label>
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_3"><small>Please enter the address that is on your credit card</small></p> 
        </li>       <li class="section_break">
      <h3>Shipping Information</h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="ship_name">Name </label>
        <span>
            <input id="ship_first" name= "ship-first" class="element text" maxlength="15" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="ship_first" name= "ship-first" class="element text" maxlength="15" size="5" value=""/>
            <label>Middle</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="ship_last" name= "ship_last" class="element text" maxlength="15" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>Last</label>
        </span> <p class="guidelines" id="guide_11"><small>Please enter the person you want the product shipped to</small></p>
        </li>       <li id="li_7" >
        <label class="description" for="ship_address">Shipping Address </label>

        <div>
            <input id="ship_street" name="ship_street" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="ship_street">Street Address</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="ship_street_2" name="ship_street_2" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="ship_street_2">Address Line 2</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="ship_city" name="ship_city" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <label for="ship_city">City</label>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <select class="element select medium" input id="ship_province" name="ship_province" onchange="showTax(this.value)">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="bc">British Columbia</option>
            <option value="alb">Alberta</option>
            <option value="sas">Saskatchewan</option>
            <option value="man">Manitoba</option>
            <option value="ont">Ontario</option>
            <option value="que">Quebec</option>
            <option value="nfl">Newfoundland & Labrador</option>
            <option value="nov">Nova Scotia</option>
            <option value="nwb">New Brunswick</option>
            <option value="pei">Prince Edward Island</option>
            <option value="ykn">Yukon</option>
            <option value="nwt">Northwest Territories</option>
            <option value="nun">Nunavut</option>
            </select>
            <label for="ship_province">Province</label>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="ship_postal" name="ship_postal" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text">
            <label for="ship_postal">Postal Code</label>
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_7"><small>Please enter the address you want your product shipped to</small></p> 
        </li>   <div id="provinceInfo"></div><div id="streetInfo"></div>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="288717" />

                <input id="submit_form" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

validation.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //global vars
    var form = $("#customForm");
    var fname = $("#bill_first");
    var lname = $("#bill_last");
    var nameInfo = $("#nameInfo");
    var email = $("#email");
    var emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");
    var creditCard = $("#credit_card");
    var ccInfo = $("#ccInfo");
    var cvv = $("#security_code");
    var cvvInfo = $("#cvvInfo");
    var street = $("#ship_street");
    var province = $("#ship_province");
    var provinceInfo = $("#provinceInfo");
    var streetInfo = $("#streetInfo");
    var description = $("#description");

    //On blur
    fname.blur(validateFname);
    lname.blur(validateLname);
    email.blur(checkEmail);
    creditCard.blur(validateCreditcard);
    cvv.blur(validateCvv);
    street.blur(validateStreet);
    province.blur(validateProvince);
    description.click(showResult);
    //On Submitting
    form.submit(function(){
        if(validateFname() & checkEmail() & validateLname() & validateCreditcard() & validateCvv() & validateStreet() & validateProvince())
            return true
        else
            return false;
    });

    //validation functions
function checkEmail(){
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null) {
        if (!document.getElementById('email').value== ""){
            httpObject.open("GET", "validate_email.php?email="+document.getElementById('email').value, true);
            httpObject.send(null);
            httpObject.onreadystatechange = setImage;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('emailInfo').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
        }
    }
}
    function getHTTPObject(){
    if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
    return null;
    }
    }

    function setImage(){
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4){document.getElementById('emailInfo').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;}

    }

    function validateFname(){
        //if it's NOT valid
        if(fname.val().length < 1){
            fname.addClass("error");
            nameInfo.text("Please enter your first name");
            nameInfo.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        //if it's valid
        else{
            fname.removeClass("error");
            nameInfo.text("");
            nameInfo.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateLname(){
        //if it's NOT valid
        if(lname.val().length < 1){
            lname.addClass("error");
            nameInfo.text("Please enter your last name");
            nameInfo.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        //if it's valid
        else{
            lname.removeClass("error");
            nameInfo.text("");
            nameInfo.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateCreditcard(){
        //if it's NOT valid
        if(creditCard.val().length < 15){
            creditCard.addClass("error");
            ccInfo.text("Please enter your credit card number");
            ccInfo.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        //if it's valid
        else{
            creditCard.removeClass("error");
            ccInfo.text("");
            ccInfo.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateCvv(){
        //if it's NOT valid
        if(cvv.val().length < 3){
            cvv.addClass("error");
            cvvInfo.text("Please enter your credit card security code");
            cvvInfo.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        //if it's valid
        else{
            cvv.removeClass("error");
            cvvInfo.text("");
            cvvInfo.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateProvince(){
        //if it's NOT valid
        if(province.val().length < 2){
            province.addClass("error");
            provinceInfo.text("Please select the province you are shipping the product to");
            provinceInfo.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        //if it's valid
        else{
            province.removeClass("error");
            provinceInfo.text("");
            provinceInfo.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: check your form method is it "POST" because you are using POST in php, if method="GET" then you should collect your sku like $_GET

Comment: I tried using GET as well and it didn't work. I'm still getting resource id number

Comment: can you paste your html form, i think there is problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field `<input type="text" id="sku" />` is missing name attribute, name attribute is used when posting to server so just correct it to

```
<input type="text" id="sku" name="sku" />
```

and it will work

Comment: yes it did work thanks so much! I can't believe I missed that :$. The only issue left is that `$itemPrice = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM user WHERE sku = \''.$sku.'\'");` doesn't work. Even when I use mysql_fetch_row I still can't get it to display the result

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query()` always returns [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) on success.

You just need to fetch the result with [mysql_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)

Comment: i think that would work but the problem is i cant pass $sku into any query because $sku is blank - it isn't retrieving the value from the form

Comment: I would try echo'ing the sku to the page. If it shows up, do what Simone said above. If it doesn't, then it's an issue with your form not POSTing the sku. I think Simone is correct.

Comment: Yeah that's what I mentioned it wont echo

Comment: So the sku is echo-ing now, but I can't get the query working

Comment: Try `echo mysql_result($itemPrice, 0);`

Comment: Thanks for the help i finally got the array working using the link you provided with mysql_fetch_array() turns out my column name and form id passed into my variable $province to return the tax result was different

Answer (score 1):

Change $sku = $_POST['sku'];
for $sku = $_GET['sku'];

And `"SELECT price FROM user WHERE sku = '.$sku.'"`
for `"SELECT price FROM user WHERE sku = \''.$sku.'\'"`

And in the form:

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="sku" />
```

replace for

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="sku" name="sku" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help adding the name field did work... but unfortunately the mysql query did not, and I can't seem to figure out why